# P5.js - Detect corner points within an image (JPG)

Tags: javascript, image-processing, processing, p5.js

I would like to detect the corner points (Top Left and Bottom Right) of the image or the "painted" area. for this purpose I want to use the javascript library p5.js. The two functions findTop() and findBottom() should recognize the corner points.

The starting point is the sketch of a cat (Figure 1). At the end the two corner points of the drawing (see figure 2) are to be recognized.

[figure 1 - cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDpEc.jpg)

[figure 2 - Detect Corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0efCa.jpg)

The procedure is as follows: With the two For loops the image array (here pixels []) is run through. For each pixel it should be checked if the content is black and if yes, compared if it is the smallest x and y values (x1|y1). For control the respective pixel pair is colored pink. The second findBottom() function works similarly. Unfortunately I am not able to find the correct coordinates, but I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

```
let img;
let x1, y1;
let x2, y2;

let wid = 720;
let hei = 400;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(wid, hei);
  img = loadImage('cat.jpg'); 
  pixelDensity(1);
}


function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
  loadPixels();
  findTop();
  findBottom();
  ColorizePixel(x1,y1);
  ColorizePixel(x2,y2);
  updatePixels();
}

function findTop() {
  x1=wid;
  y1=hei;
      
      for(let y=0; y<width; y++) {
        for(let x=0; x<height; x++) {
       
          let index = (x + y * width) * 4;

          if(pixels[index] < 255 && x < x1){
            x1 = x;
          }
                    
          if(pixels[index] < 255 && y < y1){
          y1 = y;
          }
  }
}
}

function findBottom() {
  x2=0;
  y2=0;
      
      for(let y=0; y<width; y++) {
        for(let x=0; x<height; x++) {
       
          let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
          
          if(pixels[index] < 255 && x > x2){
            x2 = x;
          }
                    
          if(pixels[index] < 255 && y > y2){
            y2 = y;
          }      
  } 
}
}

function ColorizePixel(x,y){
  let chosenPixel = (y * width + x) * 4;
  pixels[chosenPixel]=255;
  pixels[chosenPixel+1]=0;
  pixels[chosenPixel+2]=255;
  pixels[chosenPixel+3]=255;
}
```

[Result of running that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsW3y.png)

---

Edit #2

```
let img;
let x1, y1,x2, y2;

let newImage;

let wid = 720;
let hei = 400;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(wid, hei);
  img = loadImage('cat.jpg'); // Load the image
  pixelDensity(1);
}


function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
  loadPixels();
  findTop();
  findBottom();
  ColorizePixel(x1,y1);
  ColorizePixel(x2 ,y2);
  updatePixels();
  
}


function findTop() {
  
  x1=720;
  y1=400;
      
      for(let y=0; y<height; y++) {
        for(let x=0; x<width; x++) {
       
          let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
          
          if(pixels[index] < 122 && x < x1){
            x1 = x;
          }
          
          if(pixels[index] < 122 && y < y1){
          y1 = y;
          }
  }
}
}


function findBottom() {
  x2=0;
  y2=0;
      
      for(let y=0; y<height; y++) {
        for(let x=0; x<width; x++) {
       
          let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
          
          if(pixels[index] < 122 && x > x2){
            x2 = x;
          }
                    
          if(pixels[index] < 122 && y > y2){
            y2 = y;
          }      
  } 
}
}

//Farebe Pixel Pink ein
function ColorizePixel(x,y){
  let chosenPixel = (y * width + x) * 4;
  pixels[chosenPixel]=255;
  pixels[chosenPixel+1]=0;
  pixels[chosenPixel+2]=255;
  pixels[chosenPixel+3]=255;
}
```

[Result of running that code #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqOeb.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added a picture of the result below the code. The X coordinate (x1) of my left point above is displayed correctly. Unfortunately, the value for the Y coordinate (y1) is 0.
For the findBottom() method, the values are x2=399 and y2=311.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill the background with white opaque color before drawing the image and before detecting the corners:

```js
function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  image(img, 0, 0);

  // [...]
}
```

Comment: @MasterKneater Have you tried it? I tested it and it solved the problem for me. There may also be a problem with the jpg format. The format is compressed and not all of the white background will be at the end (255, 255, 255). The colors channels can vary slightly, e.g. (253, 254, 252).

Comment: Indeed! It works! :-) Thank you very much. This has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues.

##### the loops

Your loops run y to *width* instead of height, and x to *height* instead of width. I didn't spot that earlier.

##### JPEG

You are working with a JPEG file. That means *lossy* compression.

Flat colors won't stay flat.

**Don't** expect white to be *precisely* 255.

Pick a less strict threshold, or else you might "catch" an entire jpeg block instead of just the non-white pixels, because with severe enough compression, a block that contains *some* different pixels will cause all of them to distort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Issue #1 the loops

Indeed, I have exchanged x with y. I have corrected this now and the code should be correct again. Thanks again!

Issue #2 JPEG

Actually I already thought of this and set the threshold to 122 (middle gray). Unfortunately, this did not result in any change...  

For a better overview I have updated the code under Edit#2. I also added the new result image.